# What is the difference between 1 and +1

Tags: discussion, up-votes

What is the difference between 1 and +1/0, When you upvote and click on 1 it turns into a +1/0.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first '1' display shows the balance of votes. The second '+1/0' breaks out the up and down votes. This is more clearly visible in an answer such as https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15255/67

[image]
[image]

Comment: That makes sense :D